# Choosing multiple values from a Maxima list based on a list of indices

Tags: arrays, list, indices, maxima

Let's say that I had a Maxima list of indices, say `indexlist = [1,3,5]`,
and a list of values, for example `valuelist = [1,2,3,4,5]`. What is the syntax for choosing the elements of `valuelist` based on the indices in `indexlist` on a single line? I've tried

```
values : valuelist[indexlist]; /*Should return [1,3,5]*/
```

which obviously didn't work since I'm feeding a list to the selection operator `[]`, that expects a nonnegative integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in syntax for that. The idiom which I usually use is:

```
somevals : makelist (valuelist[i], i, indexlist);
```

Note that `values` is a built-in global variable; it is the list of symbols which have values assigned to them. See `? values` and maybe also `? infolists`.